# Taking the current item from the loop before return in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I use **.NET Core 5, Onion Architecture**.
I would like to know if it is possible to print in view the current item from a loop that takes place in a service that is called from the controller.
The item does not have to be received in the controller on return because I want to receive the current item from the loop and be able to send it to view as well, until the loop is completed.

I want to do this because I have to read a lot of information from an excel that will be entered into the database. And I want to show the progress (what element it reached, the information associated with that line, and how many elements are left to go).

Thank you

Comment: "I would like to know if it is possible to print" what about `Console.WriteLine`? Or how do you want to print it?

Comment: What you want is a typical job for AJAX. In regular .NET MVC, a `Model` object is prepared once (with all the data), when ready this Model gets attached to a `View` once, which then gets rendered once. You could try to implement timed polling using javascript from inside the rendered View.

Comment: Print = show in TextArea in HTML

Comment: I do not whant to get a List of all objects, i want to recieve current object from loop and make a live show.

Comment: From your description, it seems that you want to create a real time application and show the progress. If that is the case, you could consider creating a [SignalR application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0), then in the background task or the handler method, send message to the client and show the progress. Reference: [Send messages from outside a hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0)